# Expected time between calls

Tags: probability

Problem: "In a call center, three employees on average receive calls every $a,b,c$ minutes respectively, and have a probability of forwarding a call to a supervisor that is $p,q,r$ respectively.  What is the average time between calls for the supervisor?"

So if you let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the time between calls for each employee and $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ equal to $1$ if employee forwards and $0$ otherwise, how do you get $Z$ the time between calls for the supervisor? Is $Z=\min(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ if all $Y_i=1$, $Z=\min(X_i,X_j)$ if $Y_i=Y_j=1$ but the other $Y_k=0$ and $Z=X_i$ if $Y_i=1$ but all other $Y_j=0$ and finally $Z=0$ if all $Y_i=0$? I can compute the expectation of this $Z$ but I am not sure if that's the idea here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Poisson process thinning and aggregating.

The calls arrive at a Poisson rate of $\lambda_a = 1/a$, $\lambda_b = 1/b$, and $\lambda_c = 1/c$ calls per minute respectively.  The thinned rate of each process, representing the rate of calls that are forwarded to the supervisor, are simply $$\lambda_a' = p/a, \quad \lambda_b' = q/b, \quad \lambda_c' = r/c.$$  Then the total rate of calls forwarded to the supervisor is Poisson with rate $$\lambda_t = \lambda_a' + \lambda_b' + \lambda_c' = \frac{p}{a} + \frac{q}{b} + \frac{r}{c}$$ calls per minute.  The mean interarrival time of calls to the supervisor is just the reciprocal of this rate.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you model each employee's calls as three independent Poisson processes with rates $1/a$, $1/b$, and $1/c$ calls per minute.

Then the three processes "supervisor calls from the $i$th employee" ($i=1,2,3$) are also independent Poisson processes, but now with rates $p/a$, $q/b$, and $r/c$ calls per minute. See ["thinning of Poisson processes"](http://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html).

Finally, the combined process of all the supervisors calls becomes a Poisson process with rate $\frac{p}{a} + \frac{q}{b} + \frac{r}{c}$ calls per minute. See ["superposition of Poisson processes"](https://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html#sup).